# Soundwave into a circle in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, distort

I have a soundwave in Illustrator that looks like this:

[image]

It's a group made of strokes. I'd like to make it into a cirle like that:

[image]

I played around with distort and warp options but couldn't achieve this. How can I bend the soundwave?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a Brush with the Brush Palette:

Window -> Brushes

Select your sound waves (with no background, just the dots), then drag and drop into the Brushes palette

[image]

Select Pattern Brush
[image]

Try the default settings. They're usually alright.
[image]

Draw a Circle with the Ellipse Tool, switch to no fill, and add any stroke color
[image]